# Close PopupMenu on pointer press and run it

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, windows-store

In my Windows Store app, I create an show a `PopupMenu` like this:

```
var menu = new PopupMenu();
menu.Commands.Add(new UICommand("Test", (command) =>
{
    //
}));

var chosenCommand = await menu.ShowForSelectionAsync(GetElementRect(element),
                                                     Placement.Below);
```

Everything works correctly. However, when I right click on the GridView on my page, I want to both close the `PopupMenu` and change the selection at the same time. Currently I have to click twice. Once to dismiss the popup and the other to change the selection. Is there some way to do this?

Comment: What's the implementation of the right click event ?

Comment: @LoulG. It really doesn't matter. As long as it doesn't get fired up. When I set a breakpoint on the handler, it only gets fired up after the popup gets dismissed.

Comment: So you have a dependency of PopupMenu on DataGrid. You should ctor inject your DataGrid instance in a PopupMenu subclass. So that when you intercept your first clic, you can interact directly with your DataGrid instance in the PopMenu Clic Handler. But i'm affraid you will have to hit test the clic position in order to know which row to select...